# New storage, How to divi it up

Tags: raid

About to receive out new HP P2000 SAS enclosure. it will be connected to three servers running VMware. it will have 24 x 300 Gig SAS disks.

I have DC's Print servers, File servers, Exchange, SQL, SCCM, Lync, AppV, a few terminal servers and a few other / less important ones.

How would you divide up the storage, what raid configurations would you use and where would you place the VM's across these arrays (bearing in mind things like Exchange wants three separate disk areas (System, Databases, Logs))

Joe

Comment: [Welcome to ServerFault, please read the FAQ.](http://serverfault.com/faq)  "Do my job for me"/"architect my environment for free" questions are not all that well received here.

Comment: There's no simple answer to this, and you need to honestly consider whether its not worth paying someone to do this, as you seem to be in a little over your head.

Comment: Shouldn't you have decided what disks you wanted *before* you got the disk array?

Comment: Also don't put your primary DC in a VM...

Comment: The choice of hardware came down to cost, yes I could have opted for less storage, slower drives, or less drives. That's the max we could get here, when they are very reluctant to spend any cash, thats what I could get away with, so that's what we went for...
I'm not asking anyone to 'do my job for me' thankyou. I would just like to gather other peoples general experiences that might be worth taking into account. I'm sorry storage isn't my strong point, but I am the one guy that has to look after all those applications along with  "That's electronic, Joe can sort it..."

Answer (score 1):

Why 24? Presumably it's one of the 25-slot models?

Anyway create 2 x 12 disk R10 arrays and present them as 2TB (plus the remainder at the end) logical disks - that's it, nothing more to do.

Comment: P2000 G3 is a 24-bay unit.

Comment: I buy so many of those D2700's I forgot they're 3 banks of 8, cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'd break it up into 2 or 3 arrays of RAID 1+0. Don't worry about splitting Exchange across arrays... just use separate VMDK's.